# echo "<script>" não funciona

Tags: php

Boa noite, estou tentando fazer uma verificação no meu site. Se o saldo do cliente, que é definido por uma $_SESSION.

Se o mesmo possuir um saldo menor que o preço do produto, ele teria que fazer isto:

```
$saldo = $_SESSION['saldo'];

$procuraPreco = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT preco FROM infs WHERE id='$id'"); 

$retornaPreco = mysqli_fetch_all($procuraPreco,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$preco = $retornaPreco[0]['preco'];
if(isset($_POST['comprar'])) {
if($saldo < $preco) {
die('<script>alert("Pedido recusado. Razão: Saldo insuficiente"); window.location = "shop.php";</script>;'); 

}
```

Só que o alert não é mostrado na página e ele só aparece no response (F12):

```
<script>alert("Pedido recusado. Razão: Saldo insuficiente"); window.location = "shop.php";</script>
```

Nota: eu faço um POST na mesma página que o cliente clica pra comprar.

Comment: Algum erro no console?

Comment: Não, nenhum....

Answer (score -3):

Tente isso

```
$procuraPreco = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT preco FROM infs WHERE 
id='$id'"); 

$retornaPreco = mysqli_fetch_all($procuraPreco,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

$preco = $retornaPreco[0]['preco'];
if(isset($_POST['comprar'])) {
$saldo = $_SESSION['saldo'];

if($saldo < $preco) {
echo die("<script>alert("Pedido recusado. Razão: Saldo insuficiente"); 
window.location = "shop.php";</script>;"); 

}
```

Comment: isso não está correcto. você tem alguns erros de sintaxe. nao concatena "<script> com o shop.php